# 'Throwaway line' in sentence

Tags: word-meaning, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

'The process is to mention the fact you work largely from personal   introductions, as a throwaway line, at the first meeting.'
Could you please help me to know the exact meaning of "throwaway line" here?

Comment: A throwaway line is a casual aside. The sentence here has a slight ambiguity about what's mentioned, but I think it's meaning is "As a casual, seemingly unimportant bit of conversation, say that personal introductions are important for your work."

Comment: Thank you so much.